# Delete all indexes of specific route in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to delete index on specific route.

Following is the way to delete index all. But I am not seeing any way to provide routing in that.

I am using multi tenant using routing. So only one routing index I need to delete when one tenant is deleted.

```js
client.indices.delete({
    index: '_all'
}, function(err, res) {

    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Indexes have been deleted!');
    }
});
```

How can we delete all index from only specific routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr you cannot issue a route in a delete

you can do a [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/docs-delete-by-query.html), assuming you have a key you can filter down on, as you cannot provide routing there either

your best bet might be to put the data into user specific indices